# API protection from spoof referrer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, api, security, authentication

I have a project with a rails-api backend and an angular repo running on a separate, nginx server. The front end makes normal JSON requests to the API, but I have some internal methods that I want only our front end to make. So far I've been using referrer protection as a whitelist for our front end servers, but I know that can be spoofed.

*How can I prevent an attacker from creating accounts through these internal methods and flooding the server with requests?*

The other solution i considered was to send a CSRF token token to the front end on every request and then require the front end to send that with every request. I don't like that idea either, as the attacker can also make a request to this endpoint to get the CSRF token everytime he makes a request.

Am I missing anything obvious here? How people are tackling this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't hear anything in your description that makes your use case different from a regular, non-angularized app.

If I have a regular rails app serving a "signup" page, there's nothing preventing a malicious user from scripting an infinite loop of signups on that page. This seems to be the problem you're describing, but the problem **seems** different because of the distinction you're making in your head between APIs that are intentionally public and those that are for internal use.

The typical solution for this is to use a captcha or something, to make sure you've got a human on the other end of the API request.

Answer (score 0):

Frontend js sources are available to any user. Even obfuscated, the can be used for reverse engineering.

It seems to be your application architecture issue, that your front-end allows user to make some actions, that are restricted for him.

Probably you should provide more information about your app here. Or review and change apps architecture.

Comment: Does this mean that any website which separates it's front-end and back-end is allowing anyone (with enough persistence) to use any function on their site programatically?

Comment: Well, it is the core concept of HTTP protocol. Frontend is just a human-friendly interface.
So you should share with the internet only that interfaces, that can be accessable by anyone.